# How to avoid content of span break in two lines?

Tags: css, html

I have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLL9R/). When I resize the window the span is broken into two lines. How do I prevent that? I want the whole span to go to the second line.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="dvContainer">
            <span style="border:1px;border-style:solid;margin-right:5px;padding:5px;">some text for the first span</span>
            <span style="border:1px;border-style:solid;margin-right:5px;padding:5px;">second text for second span</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit:

I need them next to each other, but when I resize the screen I want the whole div to break the line, thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use nowrap:

```
span{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer. Other options include 1) the nonstandard but universally supported `nobr` markup and 2) replacing all spaces by no-break spaces (but this won’t always suffice if hyphens or special characters appear). Setting `display` to `block` or `inline-block` is *not* sufficient, as one can see by testing in a sufficiently narrow browser window.

Answer (score 4):

Add `display:block;` in your both spans

see this  [design](http://jsbin.com/oqeteh/12/edit)

or

http://jsfiddle.net/hLL9R/

Answer (score 3):

Little more cross-browser (i mean old IE and inline-blocks)

```
span { display:block; float:left }
```